# Does Oracle DB allows non-stored procedures to be executed?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a kind of scripting in my app allowing a user to execute arbitrary SQL on my Oracle RBO DB. Not just a select/update but something complicated with loops. But not a stored procedure also (there is no any reason to store such code persistently).

Is there such a thing in Oracle - "non-stored procedure" - and how is it called?

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Anonymous_block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

It's called an "anonymous PL/SQL block".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i8859

Comment: So how do I call an "anonymous block" with supplied parameters from later in my SQL script?